# Openpyxl FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have been trying to get openpyxl working with pycharm but the excel documents appear with a question mark, and when I try to run code it says filenotfounderror

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("transactions.xlsx")
print(wb)
```

I expect the output to be the cell values but instead i get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/nicol/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/excel_work.py", line
>   3, in 
>       wb = xl.load_workbook("transactions.xlsx")   File "C:\Users\nicol\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 311, in load_workbook
>       data_only , keep_links)   File "C:\Users\nicol\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 126, in **init**
>       self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)   File "C:\Users\nicol\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 98, in _validate_archive
>       archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')   File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1204, in **init**
>       self.fp = io.open(file, filemode) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transactions.xlsx'

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Try to use the formatting tools in the editor to improve readability of your questions.

Comment: Try adding the Full Path to the File.

Answer (score 1):

Add full path to the file like:

`C:\Users\mee\Desktop\Test`

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("C:\Users\mee\Desktop\Test\transactions.xlsx") ' Change your path
print(wb)
```

Answer (score 1):

**you must use full path **
**or change directory**
**for example**

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
os.chdir("c:/user/sam/desktop/test")
wb = xl.load_workbook("transactions.xlsx")
print(wb)
```

**transaction in test folder**

Answer (score 0):

It is also always a good idea to check if the "filename string" actually refers to a file. In order to check this, use something like

```
import os

absolute_filename = r"C:\Users\mee\Desktop\Test\transactions.xlsx"

if not os.path.isfile(absolute_filename):
   print("ERROR: File not found!")
   exit(-1)
```

This way you can be sure the file is actually there! If it isn't, all libraries (e.g. openpyxl) will throw some sort of error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. It worked with me when I copied the relative path, which is the path starting from the project name.

from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Projects/automate_excel/book1.xlsx')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEA3Y.png)

I hope it will work with you! also, make sure that your excel file and you Python file are in the same folder.